# Evaluate $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{\ln(1+n^4)-\ln(n^2)}{\sin^2(\frac{1}{n})}$

Tags: calculus, limits

> $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\ln(1+n^4)-\ln(n^2)}{\sin^2(\frac{1}{n})}$$

I am trying to solve this without L'hospital, the limit can be a number or $\pm \infty$

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\ln(1+n^4)-\ln(n^2)}{\sin^2(\frac{1}{n})}$$

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\ln(\frac{1+n^4}{n^2})}{\sin^2(\frac{1}{n})}$$

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\ln(\frac{n^4}{n^2})}{\sin^2(\frac{1}{n})}$$

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\ln(n^2)}{\sin^2(\frac{1}{n})}$$

Can I say that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}{\ln(n^2)}=\infty$ and $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{\sin^2(\frac{1}{n})}=\infty$ So $\infty\cdot \infty= \infty$?

Comment: $\lim_{n \to \infty}{\sin^2(\frac{1}{n})}=0$

Comment: @MathMajor right, edited

Comment: You couldn't use L'Hopital, anyway, because this limit is not representable as an "indeterminate form"

Comment: @ThomasAndrews but we may be able to bring it to an indeterminate form

Comment: @gbox I suppose, by why convert a "determinate" form (that is, one which has a known limit) into and indeterminate form just to apply L'Hopital to get the result you knew from the original form? :)

Answer (score 3):

Just note that $\log(n^4+1)-\log(n^2)>\log(n^2)$ and $|\sin x|<|x|$ so you have that $$\frac{\ln(1+n^4)-\ln(n^2)}{\sin^2(\frac{1}{n})}>n^2\log(n^2).$$

Comment: or just note $\sin^2 (1/n)<1.$

Comment: How did we get to $n^2$?

Comment: From $|\sin x|<|x|$ you get that $\frac{1}{\sin^2(1/n)}>n^2$.

Answer (score 2):

Near $+\infty $,
$$\frac {1}{n^2}+n^2\sim n^2$$
$$\ln (\frac {1}{n^2}+n^2)\sim 2\ln (n) $$

$$\sin (\frac {1}{n})\sim \frac {1}{n} $$
the function equivalent to $$2n^2\ln (n) $$ and the limit is $+\infty $.